# How to configure a Laravel application to use heroku PostgreSQL hobby dev?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku

I am currently working on a Laravel project. The default database connection points to the mySQL driver. How to change the driver to Postgres and use the credentials provided by heroku?

Comment: This is a very broad description. Please provide details of the problem and tell us what your tried so far.

Comment: @Siegmeyer I have tried changing the environment variable values in the .env file to match the credentials provided by Heroku. However, the .env file is not a part of the commit(added in .gitignore). I need a way for Heroku to populate the correct environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add the below code on top of the database configuration file.

```
$host = env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
$database = env('DB_DATABASE', '');
$username = env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge');
$password = env('DB_PASSWORD', 'forge');


if($databaseUrl = getenv('DATABASE_URL')) {

    $url = parse_url($databaseUrl);

    $host = $url['host'];
    $username = $url['user'];
    $password = $url['pass'];
    $database = substr($url['path'], 1);
}
```

Now in the same file change the value of the pgSQL key like this,

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => $host,
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => $database,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ]
```

Now login to your heroku account, under the settings tab of your project add two configuration variables,

1. Key: DATABASE_URL and value: the connection string provided by heroku while creating the hobby dev instance
2. Key: DB_CONNECTION and value: pgsql