# How do I make my Laravel project on Heroku use Heroku Postgres?

Tags: php, database, laravel, postgresql, heroku

I have been working on a project that requires I set it up in Heroku. The Database I have been using thus far locally is mySQL, but I am looking to use Postgre when the project is on Heroku.

I have done a large amount of searching but have yet to find an answer as to how I configure my Laravel project to use Postgres and how do I perform basic functions such as adding a new database to Postgres.

If there is an alternative way to just use mySQL as is that would be great.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: problem was addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488070/how-to-configure-a-laravel-application-to-use-heroku-postgresql-hobby-dev

Answer (score 2):

Heroku places (once you provision a Heroku Postgres instance) the database credentials in the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, in the following format:

```
postgres://username:password@hostname:port/database
```

Now, you could manually fill out your `DB_HOST`, `DB_USERNAME`, etc. `.env` vars from this, but there's a better way: you can parse the URL in your `config/database.php` file.

> **Note:** Newer versions of Laravel now support a `DATABASE_URL` `.env` value directly. No need to parse anymore.

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => parse_url(env('DATABASE_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST),
    'port' => parse_url(env('DATABASE_URL'), PHP_URL_PORT),
    'database' => ltrim(parse_url(env('DATABASE_URL'), PHP_URL_PATH), '/'),
    'username' => parse_url(env('DATABASE_URL'), PHP_URL_USER),
    'password' => parse_url(env('DATABASE_URL'), PHP_URL_PASS),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

(Make sure you set `DB_CONNECTION` to `pgsql` so this connection is used!)

> how do I perform basic functions such as adding a new database to Postgres

You don't. A Heroku Postgres instance comes with one database.

Comment: Side note: If you're going to use Postgres, you should be doing so locally too - there can be differences between the two, so you may find that some migrations don't work etc. Otherwise, there are third-party Heroku providers for MySQL databases. https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb-maria or you could just spin up something like an AWS RDS instance and point your config at it.

Comment: Great, thank you for the assistance, I do have one more question, there is already a pgsql entry in the database.php, should I replace it with the connection you gave me above?

Comment: @TimothyHayes That's up to you. You could create a *new* connection titled something like `'heroku'` instead of `'pgsql'` and set `DB_CONNECTION` to that. Personally, I just use the one and set my local `.env` to have a `DATABASE_URL` setting that has my localhost settings in it.

Comment: Cheers for all the help mate

Comment: Thanks, this works, here's how my `.env` looks like in case someone needs for reference: 
`DATABASE_URL=postgres://homestead:secret@127.0.0.1:5432/getbookmark`